# Regarding C Static/Non Static Float Arrays (Xcode, Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop, static

Basically I have a class method that returns a `float array`. If I return a `static array` I have the problem of it being too large or possibly even too small depending on the input parameter as the size of the array needed depends on the input size. If I return just a `float array[arraysize]` I have the size problem solved but I have other problems.

Say for example I address each element of the `non-static float array` individually e.g.

```
    NSLog(@"array[0] %f array[1] %f array[2] %f",array[0],array[1],array[2]);
```

It prints the correct values for the array. However if I instead use a loop e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
 {
    NSLog(@"array[%i] %f",i,array[i]);
 }
```

I get some very strange numbers (apart from the last index, oddly). Why do these two things produce different results? I'm aware that its bad practice to simply return a `non static float`, but even so, these two means of addressing the array look the same to me.

Relevant code from class method (for non-static version)...

```
    float array[arraysize];

    //many lines of code later

    if (weShouldStoreValue == true) {
         array[index] = theFloat;
         index = index + 1;
     }

    //more lines of code later

    return array;
```

Note that it returns a (float*).

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to return a local variable from your function and so you're seeing undefined behaviour. Can you post the (relevant parts of the) function that returns the array ?

Comment: I tried your code in one function and it works fine. I agree wit @PaulR that you may using an invalid variable allocated on stack.

Comment: I updated with some code from the class method. And thanks for taking a look.

Comment: OK - you can't return a local variable from within a function - it goes out of scope when the function returns - you either need to allocate the array outside the function and pass it as a parameter, or dynamically allocate it within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, array dies when you exit from the method or function scope.
You can do this using malloc in plain C:

```
float* array= malloc(arraysize*sizeof(float));

//many lines of code later

if (weShouldStoreValue == true) {
     array[index] = theFloat;
     index = index + 1;
 }

//more lines of code later

return array;
```

Don't forget to free the memory associated.
If you got habit to use the garbage collector and to con't care about the memory, wrap the malloc's data into a NSData object so that it will be freed, allocating with a method like this one:

```
+ (id)dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length freeWhenDone:(BOOL)freeWhenDone;
// Pass YES to the freeWhenDone argument
```

But at this point why not using a NSMutableArray of numbers?

Comment: Using float* array= malloc(arraysize*sizeof(float)); seems to be a promising route, thanks. And I didn't use NSMutableArray to try reuse some code I wrote earlier. 

However, I'm quite new to the c/objective c scene. When do I free the memory? After I return array in the class method?

Comment: You free it when you don't need to use it anymore.Or wrap it into NSData and if you are using ARC that will be freed when there are no references to that NSData object.

Comment: But, say in my main I have:
float *arrayMain = [instance methodReturnArray:parameter]
Do I just have to free arrayMain or is there another copy somewhere of "array" that was in the class method?

Comment: There isn't a copy, malloc'd memory is in the heap.So that memory needs to be freed.So you say *arrayMain = [instance methodReturnArray:parameter], there isn't any automatic reference count to that memory, you strongly decide when to allocate it and when to deallocate it.Then you use arrayMain in the way that you want it.After this you call free(arrayMain).